How to Wake Up a .NET MAUI App in the Background Using OneSignal on Android?
So I am developing an app on .net mau, after implementing one signal push notification I am able to receive a push notification inside my app the challenge I am facing right now is whether it is possible to wake up the app after the request is received
This is my code so far I have created a service, I was able to hit the breakpoint after the notification is received not sure what to do next
[Service(Name = "my.namespace.ExampleNotification")]
public class NotificationServiceExtension : Java.Lang.Object, INotificationServiceExtension
{
    public void OnNotificationReceived(INotificationReceivedEvent e)
    {
        if (!App.IsAppInBackground)
            e.PreventDefault();
        else
        {
            //Intent launchIntent = new Intent(e.Context, typeof(MainActivity)); // Replace MainActivity with your app's main activity
            //launchIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
            //e.Context.StartActivity(launchIntent);

            Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)); // Replace MainActivity with your app's main activity
            launchIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            Application.Context.StartActivity(launchIntent); // Launch app to foreground
        }
    }
}


Did you read the official document about Restrictions on starting activities from the background? On the Android 10 and heigher version, user need to tap the notification to wake up the app.

No, I didn't check it actually answers my question, thanks.

First of all, you can read the official document about the Restrictions on starting activities from the background.
And then you can refer to the official document about Start an Activity from a Notification.
Waking up the app from the notification tapped event is a better choice than from the notification received event.
